# Есть сервис где можно получить по get запросу 500-511 ошибки?

Tags: http, get, httpclient, http-server

Делаю приложение и хотелось бы проверить работу с ошибками, но негде =(

Comment: <https://habr.com/ru/post/511422/> поиском сразу нашел вот это

Comment: @Сергей а сайт http://httpme.tk/ не доступен =(

Comment: увы. могу только посоветовать посмотреть на сам код и понять, можно ли на другой сервер прицепиться. Или погуглить в анлоязычном сегменте.

Comment: https://httpbin.org/ раздел статус кодов попробуйте. Там урлы вида https://httpbin.org/status/<code>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если какого то нужного Вам сервиса нет - его можно просто сделать!

Представляю Вам следующие адреса, которые отвечают соответствующими кодами:

[code301.junecat.ru](https://code301.junecat.ru)

[code302.junecat.ru](https://code302.junecat.ru)

[code401.junecat.ru](https://code401.junecat.ru)

[code404.junecat.ru](https://code404.junecat.ru)

[code410.junecat.ru](https://code410.junecat.ru)

[code500.junecat.ru](https://code500.junecat.ru)

[code501.junecat.ru](https://code501.junecat.ru)

...

[code511.junecat.ru](https://code511.junecat.ru)

### [Ссылка на гитхаб](https://github.com/junecat/code500)

Сервис работает по HTTP и по HTTPS, сертификаты от летсэнкрипта, форсить https я не стал (мне кажется, это помешало бы использованию этих имен в тестах)

Как я сделал: у меня уже был домен, купленный для личного использования.

Это один очень простой сервис, который запущен в докер-контейнере, анализирует URL и для разрешенных имен в домене третьего уровня (то есть, в имени, которое перед junecat.ru) выдаёт соответсвующие HTTP-коды.

Выглядит примерно так:

[image: 404 and 500 http codes]

Теперь замечания.

1. Вообще говоря, список кодов

[https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Список_кодов_состояния_HTTP](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_HTTP)

более обширен. И, самое главное, для тестирования некоторых кодов мало выдать код: нужно еще и доьбавить соответвующее поле в заголовок: например, для тестирования кода 301 ("запрошенный документ был окончательно перенесен на новый URI, указанный в поле Location заголовка") нужно выдать еще и поле Location в заголовке, причем, чем то корректно заполненное.

2. Сначала я ломал голову, как сделать такую шткуку в архитектуре типа MVC, но я так ине придумал, как надо правильно написать контрллер. Хотя, казалось бы - его единственная задача - выдавать код ошибки в зависимости от адреса.

Поэтому я взял "карманный" Kestrel и написал все применительно к нему.

Если кто то подскажет мне, как это делать в более "классическом" исполнении - это было бы интересно, из чистого любопытства - всегда полезно понять, на чём ты споткнулся...

Ну, и еслим я забыл какой то код, а он пользуется популярностью - Вы тоже можете написать в комменатриях, я добавлю. Вообще, если это можно как то улучшить - я готов :-)